# Should we edit questions to match how they were answered?

Tags: discussion, editing, questions

Consider this question: [Best strategy to learn programing for graduate research data analysis in biology](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26647/learning-matlab-and-or-excel-for-graduate-research-data-analysis-textbook-recom)

This question attracted interesting answers (I'm excluding mine from this judgment). Most of them are about not using books to learn neither Matlab nor Excel.

An edit example would be to change the title to something along the line: 'Best strategy to learn programing for graduate research data analysis in biology (OP would need to narrow the field down)'

This is a special case, my question is in the general sense. **Is it appropriate to edit questions to fit the scope of their answers?**

Comment: Can you specify the exact edit you had in mind? I think answers to this question depend on the extent of the change to the question.

Comment: @ff524 added an edit example.

Comment: Your question is nice. Because if the person edits his question, the answers may not meet the newer questions and if he post a new question it may be flagged as a duplicate one. What should be exactly done? I am waiting for answers to your meta question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Great question. I would propose that the answer is **yes, after some time (>2 days) has passed since last activity**. Relatedly, this should be a rare occurrence.

My rationale is that once the question has been viewed, edited, commented on, and answered, it's value is in it's searchability. After two days of quiet, it's probably safe to say that the question is in it's "final form" and won't be significantly altered any more. At that point we can edit the question title to ensure that it can be easily found via keyword searches.